# github actions exclude pull requests from a branch

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

Say I have a workflow that runs on every PR to master which starts with:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
```

I'd like to skip all jobs if the PR is coming from the `depbot` branch. Something like:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    head_ref-ignore:
      - depbot
```

I think you can skip all the steps (one at a time) using

```yaml
 if: startsWith(github.head_ref, 'depbot') == false
```

But it is not what I want, as it would still initiate the job. How can I achieve that at the launch level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it is not what I want, as it would still initiate the job.

That means you would need a "gatekeeper" job which would be initiated (and check github.head_ref), and, through [job dependency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#creating-dependent-jobs), would call the second one only if the right condition is fulfilled.

But the point is: you need at least one job to start, in order to check a condition.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-ignoring-branches-and-tags), you can't achieve want you want at the workflow level, as it's based on `base branches`.

Therefore, **those implementations below won't work**.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:    
      - 'master'    # matches refs/heads/master
      - '!depbot'   # excludes refs/heads/depbot
```

Or

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches-ignore:    
      - 'depbot'   # ignore refs/heads/depbot
```

---

*EDITED ANSWER*

#### Workaround

A solution could be to use a `setup job` checking the `github.head_ref` context variable, and setting an output that would be used in an expression to run the following jobs if the condition is fulfilled.

Something like this:

```
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      condition: ${{ steps.condition.outputs.condition }}
    steps:
      - id: condition
        run: |
          if [[ ${{ github.head_ref }} == *"depbot"* ]]; then
             echo "condition=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
             echo "condition=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT  
          fi

  other-job:
    needs: [setup]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.condition }} == 'true'
    steps:
       [ ... ]
```

The thing is, **this workflow will always trigger**, it will just not perform the desired operations if the condition isn't fulfilled.

Comment: This applies to the base branches specified. I was looking for a way to ignore PRs 'from' specific head branches.